# How to copy/paste tables from Excel to a Word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to copy/paste tables from an Excel sheet toward a .docx. I have a word #tableauxvdd which I want to replace by my tables.

So I wrote this code

```
     With word_fichier.Range
         With .Find
             .ClearFormatting
             .Replacement.ClearFormatting
             .Text = "#tableauxvdd"
             .Replacement.Text = "#tableauxvdd"
             .Forward = True
             .Wrap = wdFindStop
             .Format = False
             .MatchWildcards = True
             .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceNone
         End With
             If .Find.Found = True Then
                For i = 1 To nombre_de_vdd
                    Set tblRangeVdd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info vdd " & i).Range("A1:C6")
                    tblRangeVdd.Copy
                    .PasteExcelTable _
                        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
                        WordFormatting:=False, _
                        RTF:=False
                Next
             End If
     End With
```

But its not working. Here is the tables I need to copy/paste
[image: tables]

And this is the result
[image]

And this is what i need :
[image]

Comment: And what are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: try using `.PasteExcelTable False, False, False`

Comment: @0m3r - that's what the OP is already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you write code to automate Word you need to think through what steps you would take if you were performing the task in the UI.

In a Word document, tables are always separated by a paragraph, so your code needs to do the same.

For example:

```
If .Find.Found = True Then
    For i = 1 To nombre_de_vdd
        Set tblRangeVdd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info vdd " & i).Range("A1:C6")
        tblRangeVdd.Copy
        .PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=False
        .InsertParagraphAfter
    Next
End If
```

You'll also need to add the tables in reverse order, for example:

```
If .Find.Found = True Then
    Dim tblRangeVdd As word.Range
    Set tblRangeVdd = .Duplicate
    With tblRangeVdd
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        For i = nombre_de_vdd To 1 Step -1
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info vdd " & i).Range("A1:C6").Copy
            .PasteExcelTable _
                LinkedToExcel:=False, _
                WordFormatting:=False, _
                RTF:=False
            .InsertParagraphAfter
        Next
    End With
End If
```

Comment: I understand what you said, but i tried it and it doesnt work, i have the same result as the one i posted. I tried to put the .InsertParagraphAfter at the begining of the For loop but i have the same result.

Comment: @julien1h - see edited answer.